# Java language translation library

Tags: java, translation

I'm trying to develop a translation desktop app using Java to translate some text files from Russian to English (Spanish to English is required too).

I've tried the google-api-translate and it seems to work just fine, but I'm in need of something that can work offline.

I was wondering if you are aware of something that might help me, free or not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it offline ?

Comment: Are you asking for a downloadable library that will do Russian-English translation? That's a huge piece of functionality.

Comment: It's supposed to translate very big amounts of data so I can do a text search using lucene,  an online transaction app might not be good enough because of performance and getting kicked by the translation server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that has a java api for google translate, that you would just import.

[java api](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/downloads/detail?name=google-api-translate-java-0.95.jar)

and some information on it

[info](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/)

edit:
not 100% sure if its all offline though :-/

edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207429/924071

You cannot use the google API offline, you would have to purchase a commerical software.

Comment: I've tried that as I said in my question, it uses google sites to operate. I need it to be offline (=

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: looks like http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Installation might be the solution!